# angular $resource factory pass parameter

Tags: angularjs, factory, angular-resource

I have a factory that makes some $resource calls to the server. The setData function works fine. My question is how do I pass a parameter into the factory to be used in the SubmitAttendance function? I need to pass a id to be sent to the server

```
.factory('AttendanceData', function ($resource, theConfig) {
    var serverPath = theConfig.apiURL;
    var serverKey = theConfig.apikey;
    return $resource(serverPath + '/api/Canvas/:action',
        {key: serverKey},
        {
            SetData: {method: 'GET', params: {action: "SetData" }, isArray: false},
            SubmitAttendance: {method: 'GET', params: {action: "SubmitAttendance"}, isArray: false}
        });
});
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead, returning an object exposing a method which you can throw arbitary data into.

```
.factory('AttendanceData', function ($resource, theConfig) {
    return {
        get: function (data) {
            return $resource(/* do stuff with data */)
        }
    }
});
```

then in the calling code

```
AttendanceData.get('foo');
```